# Google Uses My Reverse Record To Access Site - Is that ok? How to redirect them?

Tags: domain-name-system

Google accesses my site via my DNS reverse records e.g. static-myip.host.com instead of using the domain

In Google Webmaster tools I get DNS issues - could it be that allowing Google to access a site via reverse records is not the best thing? How can I redirect direct accesses via reverse records to the actual domain?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can redirect these accesses via httpd.conf, but I have no clue how and the documentation on this issue is small

Comment: I don't suppose it's as easy as getting your reverse DNS to match your forward DNS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new name-based virtual host matching your reverse hostname and redirect it with 301 to the correct domain (e.g. example.net):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName static-myip.host.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule (.*) http://example.net/$1 [R=301,L] 
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

This way Google bots will know that the real URL for the content is http://example.net/